# Include an application page in an application page

Tags: application-pages, content

I want to know if it is possible to include an application page in another application page?

Basically, I have an application page working with tabs. I would like to have the content change when a tab is clicked. To do this I see two possibilities:

1) Having a placeholder, and on each tab click, refreshing the place holder with the relevant content using C# code behind.

2) Having all the tabs in my application pages, and on each tab click, displaying the relevant content using javascript.

Which solution is the best? Knowing that the contents I'll show are forms, I need to be able to control them with C# code behind.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options for tab controls in an app page.  You could use a jquery tab control or a .net tab control.  Check out the following links:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13165/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Tab-Control-Using-the-MultiView-c

[.NET Tab Control Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, 
Do you know if there is a way to include the application pages in the "Views" ? Because, i may have some application pages with same id textbox, and i would like to have one code behind page for each one. If it's not possible I'll just change the IDs :)

Comment: Assuming you truly need to add another app page in the tab view rather than a form that uses the same code that is on that other app page, I think you should be able to use an iFrame within the view somehow.  That seems more complex than just adding code to the one app page that does what the other app pages.  When you mentioned forms, were you talking just a .net input form or an infopath form?

Comment: All right thanks for the informations,
I don't really know how i'm supposed to begin this, I'm quite new on SharePoint, and didn't really understand what the specifications of the projects are. And my chief project is not here for one week ... /p
I'll just go in one direction, and see what it gives. Thanks a lot for the informations ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is simply to add Code-Behind in one of the VIEWS or List Forms the best way would be to go and create your own Web Part (access to full Object Model and SPContext, etc.) and in SharePoint 2010 you can now EDIT (append **PageView=Shared&ToolPaneView=2** to the query string in address bar on any Page not exposing the EDIT button and it will switch it) those VIEW Pages and add any web parts to it.

Besides using a web part would also avoid the issues where the Application Pages are avaiable under _layouts which also means anyone could access it from the wherever they like in the farm - most confusing.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer, I will go with @sween_sp 's one.